# Retrieving data from DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I'm trying to retrieve data from the `DetailsView` control in order to input them into another database table. I've looked through other questions that others asked but none of their questions could fit into my situation, which is trying to access SQL Database. Ultimately, I couldn't find the answer I require.

Basically, my objective of the codes is to extract the second row of the DetailsView, since the first row are mostly the static headers that do not change. My DetailsView would change upon the selection of a GridView above. Hence, I'm trying to retrieve the data on the second row, explaining my usage of Rows[2] , while I presume that "Cells[]" refers to the columns.

I'm using the following codes to do so.

```
string insertQuery = "insert into SalesOrders ([pQuotation#], pServices, pQty, pDescription, [p[Price/Unit]], pNetvalue, pProgress, pClientNo values (@quotationno,@services,@quantity,@description,@priceperunit,@netvalue,@progress,@clientno)";
cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, con)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quotationno", DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text);   
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@services", DetailsView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", DetailsView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", DetailsView1.Rows[3].Cells[1].Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priceperunit", DetailsView1.Rows[4].Cells[1].Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@netvalue", DetailsView1.Rows[5].Cells[1].Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@progress", "0%");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientno", clientnolbl.Text.ToString());
```

I've been thrown the following exception:

```
Error:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index at System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) at RealClientPurchase.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Desktop\RealClientPurchase.aspx.cs:line 27
```

EDIT: 
This is the code behind file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class RealClientPurchase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clientnolbl.Text = Session["sClientNo"].ToString();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\Desktop\TemporarySter\App_Data\legitdatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd;
            string insertQuery = "insert into SalesOrders ([pQuotation#], pServices, pQty, pDescription, [p[Price/Unit]], pNetvalue, pProgress, pClientNo values (@quotationno,@services,@quantity,@description,@priceperunit,@netvalue,@progress,@clientno)";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, con);



        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quotationno", DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text);   
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@services", DetailsView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", DetailsView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", DetailsView1.Rows[3].Cells[1].Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priceperunit", DetailsView1.Rows[4].Cells[1].Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@netvalue", DetailsView1.Rows[5].Cells[1].Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@progress", "0%");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientno", clientnolbl.Text.ToString());


            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirect",
                "alert('Purchase order has been submitted! Kindly proceed to checkout.'); window.location='" +
                Request.ApplicationPath + "CurrentCheckout.aspx';", true);

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

These are the aspx codes:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ClientPortal.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="RealClientPurchase.aspx.cs" Inherits="RealClientPurchase" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Register1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [qQuotationNo], [qServices], [qQuantity], [qDate] FROM [Quotations] WHERE ([qClientNo] = @qClientNo)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="qClientNo" SessionField="sClientNo" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Register1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [qQuotationNo], [qServices], [qQuantity], [qDescription], [qPricePerQty], [qTotalPayable] FROM [Quotations] WHERE ([qQuotationNo] = @qQuotationNo)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="qQuotationNo" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Label ID="clientnolbl" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="qQuotationNo" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="125px" Width="452px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="qQuotationNo" HeaderText="Quotation No" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="qQuotationNo" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="qServices" HeaderText="Services" SortExpression="qServices" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="qQuantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="qQuantity" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="qDate" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="qDate" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" Height="50px" Width="452px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="qQuotationNo">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#DEE8F5" Font-Bold="True" />
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="qQuotationNo" HeaderText="qQuotationNo" SortExpression="qQuotationNo" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="qServices" HeaderText="qServices" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="qServices" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="qQuantity" HeaderText="qQuantity" SortExpression="qQuantity" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="qDescription" HeaderText="qDescription" SortExpression="qDescription" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="qPricePerQty" HeaderText="qPricePerQty" SortExpression="qPricePerQty" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="qTotalPayable" HeaderText="qTotalPayable" SortExpression="qTotalPayable" ReadOnly="True" />
        </Fields>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    </asp:DetailsView>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the index start from zero? For your second row, it should be Row[1]. Similarly for Cells too.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Anurag
Sir, so what you're essentially saying is for all data fields that I'm trying to retrieve the values out of, they should all be Row[1].Cells[1], but with the only difference in Controls[]?

Comment: @SarahCollins: First of all I'm no Sir..:)..I'm trying to say that index starts from zero. Your second row will be Row[1]. Now this row will have multiple cells. If you need first cell value it will be Cells[0] and so on. Why don't you debug line by line and see the value of DetailsView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Controls[0] in a quick watch. It will make things clearer. Try it.

Comment: @SarahCollins: Also I think you'll have to check for only rows,excluding the header. Something like if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)

Comment: @Anurag

I've tried doing what you said, but I'm still being thrown an exception.

Error:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index at System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCellCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) at RealClientPurchase.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Desktop\RealClientPurchase.aspx.cs:line 29    


It appears to be from a different line.

Line 29's codes are 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", DetailsView1.Rows[1].Cells[2]);

Comment: What controls do you have in your detailsview? Can you please edit your question and put the entire code?

Comment: @Anurag
Hello, I owe you my gratitude for replying!
Thank you so much for helping out.
Anyway, I've included the codebehind and the aspx markup in the original post.

Comment: @SarahCollins: I see that you've removed the Control attribute from  Row.Cells...It did the trick..didnt it? I too was wondering as to why do you have Control as an attribute. Anyways keep coding.

Comment: @Anurag
Oh no, the problem has not been solved. I tried to delete away some of the code to try to solve the issue. However, it still didn't work out. I added the codebehind and markup file thinking you could further advise me.

I'm still being thrown this exception: Error:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index at System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCellCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) at RealClientPurchase.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: I was thinking may be 1 of the cells might contain integer values can you make sure the ones that are integer  in database are being converted to integer in your code behind like Convert.Toint32(DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[?].ToString())

Comment: @Developer
I tried that and it the exception thrown was:

Error:System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell' to type 'System.IConvertible'. at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value) at RealClientPurchase.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Desktop\TemporarySter\RealClientPurchase.aspx.cs:line 27

Answer (score 4):

I've found the solution.

I changed the fields in the database table to exclude "#" and "[" or "]"
It appears these signs do not function well in a SQL statement.
Revamped codes are as follows, and they do work.

```
SqlCommand cmd;
            string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO SalesOrders (pQuotationNo, pServices, pQty, pDescription, pPricePerQty, pNetvalue, pProgress, pClientNo) values (@quotationno,@services,@quantity,@description,@priceperunit,@netvalue,@progress,@clientno)";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, con);


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quotationno", DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text.ToString());   
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@services", DetailsView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", DetailsView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", DetailsView1.Rows[3].Cells[1].Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priceperunit", DetailsView1.Rows[4].Cells[1].Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@netvalue", DetailsView1.Rows[5].Cells[1].Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@progress", "0%");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientno", clientnolbl.Text.ToString());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Good that you got the solution. Cheers Sarah.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text`?

Since your `DetailsView` has `BoundFields` only, this should work.

Regards

Comment: As of now, no exception has been thrown, however upon clicking the submit button, the data doesn't enter the database.

Comment: Sarah..edit the post to enter the new code which you have tried

Comment: Check whether you have data available in Rows[0]. You had asked initially for 2nd row, try to use Rows[1] and similar.

Comment: Hi, I've added the latest codes I've used which still didn't work.
I also removed "cmd.executenonquery()" as it was giving me some trouble as well.

The index starts from [0]. Therefore I used Row[1] to try to get the second row.

Comment: @SarahCollins: any exceptions this time?

Comment: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() is mandatory Sarah. It helps us to perform the Insert, Update, Delete operations via ADO.NET.

Comment: I've not been thrown any exceptions, however when I check the database for any new records, none were found.

Comment: If I were to enter ExecuteNonQuery();

I would get the following exception thrown:
Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The identifier that starts with 'p[Price/Unit], pNetvalue, pProgress, pClientNo values (@quotationno,@services,@quantity,@description,@priceperunit,@netvalue,@pr' is too long. Maximum length is 128. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'p[Price/Unit], pNetvalue, pProgress, pClientNo values (@quotationno,@services,@quantity,@description,@priceperunit,@netvalue,@pro'